# Native JavaFX OS X app bundle with JLink: can't change application name from `org.example.app.Main` in OS X menu items

Tags: macos, maven, javafx, java-platform-module-system, jlink

I'm using JLink to create native JavaFX app. When creating OS X app bundle, I can specify `CFBundleName` and `CFBundleDisplayName` in `Info.plist`, but I didn't find any way to set names of menu 'Hide' and 'Quit' items. What I obtain is:

[image]

How I can rename `org.example.samplejavafx.Main` to something meaningful?

**My sample project:**

I use Maven with [moditect plugin](https://github.com/moditect/moditect) (I have to use non-modular third party libraries in production). Here is the full `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>samplejavafx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <module.mainClass>org.example.samplejavafx.Main</module.mainClass>
        <module.name>samplejavafx</module.name>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/modules
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
                <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-module-info</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-module-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwriteExistingFiles>true</overwriteExistingFiles>
                            <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</buildDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                            <jvmVersion>13</jvmVersion>
                            <modules></modules>
                            <module>
                                <mainClass>${module.mainClass}</mainClass>
                                <moduleInfoSource>
                                    module ${module.name} {
                                    requires javafx.controls;
                                    requires javafx.graphics;

                                    exports org.example.samplejavafx;
                                    }
                                </moduleInfoSource>
                            </module>
                            <jdepsExtraArgs>
                                <arg>--multi-release</arg>
                                <arg>13</arg>
                            </jdepsExtraArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-runtime-image</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create-runtime-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <modulePath>
                                <path>${project.build.directory}/modules</path>
                            </modulePath>
                            <modules>
                                <module>${module.name}</module>
                            </modules>
                            <launcher>
                                <name>launcher</name>
                                <module>${module.name}/${module.mainClass}</module>
                            </launcher>
                            <compression>2</compression>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jlink-image</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--module-path</argument>
                                <argument>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/modules
                                </argument>
                                <argument>--module</argument>
                                <argument>${module.name}/${module.mainClass}</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>13</source>
                    <target>13</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Source code of `org.example.samplejavafx.Main`:

```java
package org.example.samplejavafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Label l = new Label("Hello");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(l), 640, 480);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Create OS X app bundle:

```sh
mvn clean install
mkdir -p samplejavafx.app/Contents/MacOS
cp -r target/jlink-image/* samplejavafx.app/Contents/MacOS
```

`Info.plist`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>SampleJavaFX</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>SampleJavaFX App</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.example.samplejavafx</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>smpl</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>bin/launcher</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Sample copyright</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for can be done with the new jpackage tool. See this example https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX on GitHub. With the jpackage tool you can create an app bundle which has the name you want and you can also add a proper icon to it and if you like you can also create a platform specific installer.